# Django-allauth with StackExchange: How to set it?

Tags: django, oauth, django-allauth, stackexchange-api

After successfully implemented Reddit login via Django-allauth, I'm trying to do the same with StackExchange.

I've followed the [doc](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html#stack-exchange) for this.

**1) In my Django project:**

my settings:

```
...
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    { 'stackexchange':
        { 'SITE': 'stackoverflow' } }

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'main_page'
```

and I'm using in one of my template the link:

`href="{% provider_login_url 'stackexchange' %}"`

**2) In https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth:**

I've registered to stackapps like this:

- Application Name: MyApp Description: MyApp OAuth
- Domain: localhost
- Application Website: localhost
- I've unchecked: "Enable Client side
  OAuth Flow" and "Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri".

**3) Then I put in http://localhost:8000/admin:**

- Provider: Stack Exchange
- Name: MyApp
- Client id: (the id given by stackapps)
- secret key: (the secret key given by stackapps)
- Chosen sites: example.com

Nevertheless, I've got this error:

```
KeyError at /accounts/stackexchange/login/callback/

'items'
```

Apparently, /accounts/stackexchange/login/callback/ doesn't exist because if I look in local vars from the errors:

```
            extra_data = resp.json()['items'][0]

     ...

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
resp       <Response [400]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you did not specify the `key` parameter in your StackExchange App. Go to `http://localhost:8000/admin` and edit the StackExchange app to include the app key. The app key can be found on the StackApps.com site, on the same page where you got your client id and secret.

What happens is that `django-allauth` logs you in using StackExchange provider, and using the access token returned by StackExchange, fetches the data from `/me` url (here is the [code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/stackexchange/views.py#L19)). To fetch the data, it needs the access token, the app key and the site from which to fetch the data. Without the key, StackExchange API returns

```
{
    error_id: 405,
    error_message: "`key` is required when `access_token` is passed.",
    error_name: "key_required"
}
```

As you can see, there is no key `items` in this dictionary.